# How to change date time format dynamically moment angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using moment in angular 4 ant its working fine but I want to change date and time format dynamically

Here is my code  :

```
onLangChange() {
  this.lanId = this.commonService.getCurrentLanguageCode() // 'en', 'fr', 'de'
  moment.locale(this.lanId)
}
```

But it`s not working for me

Comment: how are you using moment, through pipes  ?

Comment: _date time format_ or _language_ change?

Comment: I am using this https://medium.com/@jek.bao.choo/steps-to-add-moment-js-to-angular-cli-f9ab28e48bf0

@Dhyey

Comment: Dhyey is right. {{somemodel | mymomentjspipe:myformatvariable}}